# How to get firestore array data to Spinner in xamarin Android?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, arraylist, xamarin.android

**Please help me.**
This is my firestore reference

```
AppDataHelper.GetFirestore().Collection("users").Document(FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Uid).Collection("Items").Get().AddOnCompleteListener(this);
```

I only need Name list to Spinner

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPsHl.jpg)

This is Retrieving Data below.

```
 public void OnComplete(Task task)
            {
                
            var snapshot = (QuerySnapshot)task.Result;
                List<SItems> listofItems = new List<SItems>();
                if (snapshot.IsEmpty) return;
                var document = snapshot.Documents;
                listofItems.Clear();
    
                foreach (DocumentSnapshot user in document)
                {
                    SItems userModel=new SItems();
                    {
                        
                        userModel.ItemName = user.Get("Name").ToString();
                    };
                    listofItems.Add(userModel);
                    
                }
                
            }
```

And This Code is error.I can't add `listofItems` to `adapter`

```
ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, listofItems);
            adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
            NOrdItemSpinner.Adapter = adapter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solve!

I was change the that code

```
 List<SItems> listofItems = new List<SItems>();
```

to
List listofItems = new List();

and then that code

```
listofItems.Add(userModel);
```

to

```
listnew.Add((userModel.ItemName).ToString());
```